# Reporting each class metric

Tags: plot, keras, metrics

i am using Tensorflow/Keras to train a CNN. I have defined a custom metric to my problem. During the process, i get reports like:

```
Epoch 3/2000
57/57 - 3s - loss: 244231.4060 - custom_metric: 0.6170 - val_loss: 364119.8415 - val_custom_metric: 0.5506
```

It is a regression problem with 3 outputs. Is there anyway i can get those metric reports from each class separately?

I've seen in a paper where the author was using `binary_accuracy` as metrics, he also used TF/Keras, and even plotted in a graphic those values over all epochs.

This is the custom metric i have defined, with `Yclasses = 3` and `batch_size = 16`:

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
  truepotventolow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_true[0:batch_size,0], 4000), 'int8')
  predpotventolow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_pred[0:batch_size,0], 4000), 'int8')
  potventolow = K.sum(truepotventolow*predpotventolow)
  truepotventomed = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[0:batch_size,0], 4000) & K.less_equal(y_true[0:batch_size,0], 8500), 'int8')
  predpotventomed = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[0:batch_size,0], 4000) & K.less_equal(y_pred[0:batch_size,0], 8500), 'int8')
  potventomed = K.sum(truepotventomed*predpotventomed)
  truepotventohigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[0:batch_size,0], 8500), 'int8')
  predpotventohigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[0:batch_size,0], 8500), 'int8')
  potventohigh = K.sum(truepotventohigh*predpotventohigh)
  truedesvpadlow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_true[0:batch_size,1], 1150), 'int8')
  preddesvpadlow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_pred[0:batch_size,1], 1150), 'int8')
  desvpadlow = K.sum(truedesvpadlow*preddesvpadlow)
  truedesvpadmed = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[0:batch_size,1], 1150) & K.less_equal(y_true[0:batch_size,1], 2300), 'int8')
  preddesvpadmed = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[0:batch_size,1], 1150) & K.less_equal(y_pred[0:batch_size,1], 2300), 'int8')
  desvpadmed = K.sum(truedesvpadmed*preddesvpadmed)
  truedesvpadhigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[0:batch_size,1], 2300), 'int8')
  preddesvpadhigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[0:batch_size,1], 2300), 'int8')
  desvpadhigh = K.sum(truedesvpadhigh*preddesvpadhigh)
  truewlslow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_true[0:batch_size,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  predwlslow = K.cast(K.less_equal(y_pred[0:batch_size,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  wlslow = K.sum(truewlslow*predwlslow)   
  truewlshigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_true[0:batch_size,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  predwlshigh = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred[0:batch_size,2], 0.075), 'int8')
  wlshigh = K.sum(truewlshigh*predwlshigh)
  return (potventolow+potventomed+potventohigh+desvpadlow+desvpadmed+desvpadhigh+wlslow+wlshigh)/(batch_size*Yclasses)
```

Comment: See my answer below. Note: As you didn't provide any code or data, I can't test it, so test it and provide me results to check it.

Comment: Hello @Geeocode. Thanks for the reply. I have edited the topic with the custom metric.

Comment: Hello. First. Don't use `batchsize` as your metric will be used at the epochs' end, where the whole datasets will be evaluated. You are using the separate classes, but returns the means of the calculations on them. Is this your actual intention?

Comment: Oh, i understand... so i need to change those `0:batch_size` ranges for just `:`? And yes, that's my actual intention. So, the metric is calculated at the epoch's end, not at each batch? Then i have another question, sorry. If my train and validation data are from different sizes, how you would advise me to write the function `return`?

Comment: Sorry I said incorrectly, I meant the metric will be used per batches, but the evaluation trough all datapoints. Yes just `:` and at the `return` without `batch_size` too. You said different sizes, but if I see you well, you meant different sizes at the axis 0, which means you have the same sizes i.e. same classes, but you have more valid data, which is normal and has no effect to the form of `return`. Anyway please test it and if you have the result what you need, please accept my answer.

Comment: I see, Thank you for your help. I'll accept your answer, it helped me define the metric they way i wanted.

Comment: My pleasure! I really would like to get feedback if it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a custom metric:

```
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    return (
           keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0], threshold=0.5),
           keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true[:, 1], y_pred[:, 1], threshold=0.5),
           keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true[:, 2], y_pred[:, 2], threshold=0.5)
           )
```

Then you can pass it to the model at compile time:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', custom_metric])
```